# How do I pull each element of the array out using the Comma gem?

Tags: ruby, csv

I'm using the [Comma gem](https://github.com/crafterm/comma) with Rails. Here's my Customer Model:

```
class Customer
  include MongoMapper::Document

  key :customer_id, Integer
  key :company_id, String
  key :first_name, String, :required => true
  key :last_name, String
  key :email, Array, :unique => true, :required => true
  key :phone, Array

  comma do 
    first_name
    last_name
    email
    phone
  end
end
```

Then I render:

```
format.csv { render :csv => @all_customers }
```

`@all_customers` is just a collection of the customers for this particular environment—this part works fine.

When I export to CSV, I get these types of entires:

```
["dan@whatever.com"]
```

I know that's because email is an array, and Comma is just literally rendering the entire thing. I want:

```
dan@whatever.com
```

Normally I would do something like:

```
email[0]
```

And it would grab just that value from the array.  But trying this resulted in no difference in the exported CSV.  Still had the unnecessary brackets and quotes.

How do I just grab the element and avoid the brackets and quotes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want the first email, then

```
comma do 
    first_name
    last_name
    email do |email| email[0] end
    phone
end
```

Or if you want all the emails, then

```
comma do 
    first_name
    last_name
    email do |email| email.join(',') end
    phone
end
```

Comment: I can't upvote you yet as I haven't hit rep 15, but... you clever bastard!  Fixed that straight-away :)  Really appreciate it.